# displaying an extra field added to the database in opencart on the order page

Tags: php, mysql, twig, opencart, opencart-3

I have added an extra field to the oc_order table in an Opencart database.

However, when I try and check if it exists or displays the data in that filed, I see nothing.

I have updated the catalogue/view/theme/account/order_info.twig file with the following to test both displaying the new field and using an if statement...

```
{{ newfield }} {% if newfield == true %}
                WORKS
                {% else %}
                NOT WORKING
            {% endif %}
```

I have a '1' inset in the database but I always get the 'NOT WORKING' displayed.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: This is a common slip up when coming up against Boolean logic in a database for the first time. It is uncommon (in my experience) for a DB to interpret '1' and '0' as Boolean values. 

However I suggest you add more contextual information to your question: a code sample of the application code, some more detail on the system this is running on, and what you have tried before coming to SO. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to retrieve data from db and show it on your template you should 
First, in corresponding controller file retrieve data from DB

```
$query = "SELECT newfield FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "table_name ";
```

Than you should declare it in the same controller file

```
if ($query->rows) {
    $data['newfield'] = $query->row['newfield'];
} else {
 $data['newfield'] = '';
}
```

Now you can retrieve it in your template

```
{% if newfield %}
  WORKS {{ newfield }}
{% else %}
  NOT WORKING
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks K. B. by adding in 'newfield'   => $order_query->row['newfield'] in the model/account/order.php file - it works a treat. Thanks for you guidance

Comment: Yes, that's great.

Answer (score 0):

It's not true, right? ;)

You should either use `{% if newfield %}` as it's not empty value or you can use [defined](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tests/defined.html) function.

Twig comparisons work slightly differently than PHP versions. You can also check with `{{dump(newfield) }}` what you exactly got here, so then you can make your condition more specific, but I guess simple form as above it's enough as it's less flag.

BTW What's your output of `{{ newfield }}`? If it's empty, it means you may don't pass it correctly to the template file.